# How to use Google Sheets QUERY + IMPORTRANGE to extract values where IDs match between worksheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to populate a Google sheet (Sheet1) from another Google sheet (Reports) based on ID values matching between them. I found this solution on a similar question, and it works great when I test it using a sample of the data:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Reports!A2:Y5000"),"select Col25 where Col1 matches 
'"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Sheet1!A2:A)&"'",0)
```

But when I try to apply it to the full dataset, I get an error message that "Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters." So then I tried a simpler formula:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Reports!A2:Y7000"),"select Col25 where Col1 matches '"&$A2&"'"); 
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Reports!A7001:Y"),"select Col25 where Col1 matches '"&$A7001&"'")}
```

The first IMPORTRANGE works fine on its own, but I have to split it into two because it tells me I have too many rows (I only have ~10,000). When I split it in the above formula, I get an error that the array was not expanded because it would overwrite data.

Is there an easier way to simply pull in data based on the ID in one sheet matching the ID in another?

Comment: Wild guess but it may be due to the second query running from A7001 to Y. Perhaps try entering a large row number as the end that would cover the data but not be the full 50,000. `Reports!A2:Y25000`. My guess is even though the results are manageable the range being imported to query is not.

Comment: Thanks @KevinP. Do you mean don't split the IMPORTRANGE? I tried this using my full range: Reports!A2:Y11800. I still get an error that results are too large. I tried another split, using two ranges (Reports!A2:Y7000 and Reports!A7001:Y11800) and I get the same problem that "Array was not expanded because it would overwrite data." Still seeking a solution...

Comment: Would it be safe if you can share a sample sheet for replication purposes?

Comment: I have never seen that error populate unless it was in fact going to overwrite data. Are you certain your cells from `A2:Y11800` in the destination sheet are empty? Not a lingering value anywhere? You could use a formula like this to verify it returns 0 (no data in range) `COUNTIF($A$2:$Y,"<>")`. If the number is larger than 0 you could then try something like this to get the reference to the last row with data `=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A2:Y)*--(A2:Y<>"")))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with FILTER and MATCH:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE (URL,"Reports!Y:Y"), INDEX (IFERROR(XMATCH(IMPORTRANGE(URL,"Reports!A:A"), Sheet1!A2:A,0)>0)))
```

Comment: When I use your formula, I get the following error: FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 11825. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

Comment: Had one misplaced parenthesis, try again with new update!